# Internet Explorer 8 Developer Tools not displaying

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Within the last day, in Internet Explorer 8, the developer tools window will not show up.

When I hit F12 or use menu Tools -> Developer Tools I get the Developer Tools entry in the Task Bar but the actual window will not show up.

It has been running fine for a month or so.  I have tried rebooting with no luck.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

> [**How do I get a window back on the screen when it moved far, far away?**](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/05/11/9601136.aspx)

**From the article:**

> Switch to the application, say by clicking on its taskbar button or by
>   Alt+Tab'ing to it. Then type Alt+Space to call up the System menu: You
>   should get a window floating at the edge of the screen. Type M to
>   select Move, then press an arrow key to enter Move mode.

Additional remark by @WebSolProv:

> It would appear that something happens with IE that causes the developer tools window to be shrunk to the height of the header bar and width of about 2 inches.  By using this solution you can then move the the window into view and enlarge as usual.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much. From 3 months I'm satisfying myself with chrome debugging tools (they are also very good). Now as I've got this window back I can test things quickly on IE also. I would have given +10 if I could.

Comment: great thanks - also if you have windows 7, move the mouse of the internet explorer developer tools window.. right click on the preview window and click move, then you the arrow keys to pull it into view.

Comment: IE -- Always proves to be the developer's worst nightmare :)

Comment: hitting Maximize after alt+space was quickest for me.

Comment: I cant believe that its 2016 and I needed to know this. FTW!!

Comment: Link updated: [How do I get a window back on the screen when it moved far, far away?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090511-00/?p=18303)

Answer (score 47):

If you are on Windows 7, Windows Key + Up Arrow Key will maximize the window.

Answer (score 17):

Not related to the window issue, but in some companies, this could be due to policies. In such cases, at least for me, it worked after modifying the registry like this

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > POLICIES > MICROSOFT > INTERNET EXPLORER > IEDEVTOOLS`

and then modifying the DISABLED value to 0, which was 1 for me previously.

Answer (score 11):

I had same problem on Windows 7 when I went back to single monitor setup after having a dual monitor setup.

Use the Windows 7 keyboard shortcut for moving windows around the screen. You may need to repeat the same combination twice.

Windows Key + Left Arrow

or

Windows Key + Right Arrow

Comment: Same - this worked for me (I'd tried just alt-space+Maximize, but that wasn't enough. I had to Windows Key+Right Arrow, then drag the window to a new size. Works good, now.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting some registry keys worked for me. Try running this in a prompt

reg delete "hkcu\software\microsoft\internet explorer\iedevtools" /v windowpos

Answer (score 1):

Select by Developer Tools window by `ALT+TAB` then press `ALT+SPACE` to show window menu and select `Maximize` or type `'X'` character. The Winow will Show UP.

Answer (score 1):

If the window is off page and out of reach by the cursor you can always right click the program in the task bar, click `Move` then you can use the arrow keys to move the window back into view

Answer (score 0):

For me the menu item 'tools > developer tools' and F12 would not do anything, however the command bar 'tools' dropdown worked as well as the command bar icon.

Answer (score 0):

Run IE and hit F12 , window appears in taskbar.Right click on taskbar and select maximize. vola!! it will appear